# Cannot save the file to specific directory by wasm

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

OS : win10 64bits

Browser : edges Version 89.0.774.77 (Official build) (64-bit)

Emscripten : 1.39.7

The function saves file

```
void saveFile(const char *data, size_t length, const char *fileNameHint)
{
    // Create file data Blob
    val Blob = val::global("Blob");
    val contentArray = val::array();
    val content = val(typed_memory_view(length, data));
    contentArray.call<void>("push", content);
    val type = val::object();
    type.set("type","application/octet-stream");
    val fileBlob = Blob.new_(contentArray, type);

    std::cout<<__func__<<": fname hint = "<<fileNameHint;
    // Create Blob download link
    val document = val::global("document");
    val link = document.call<val>("createElement", std::string("a"));
    link.set("download", fileNameHint);
    val window = val::global("window");
    val URL = window["URL"];
    link.set("href", URL.call<val>("createObjectURL", fileBlob));
    link.set("style", "display:none");

    // Programatically click link
    val body = document["body"];
    body.call<void>("appendChild", link);
    link.call<void>("click");
    body.call<void>("removeChild", link);
}
```

I call it like this:

```
auto contents = generate_contents();
saveFile(contents.data(), contents.size(), "C:/users/mypath/01.jpg");
```

It works, the problem is it always save the file to the Download folder with file name "c_users_mypath_01.jpg", hint of the file is correct (C:/users/mypath/01.jpg), yet it always save the file in the download folder but not "C:/users/mypath".

Is this the limitation of the browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the limitation of the browser?

Yes, intentionally so. You can't just access arbitrary paths on user's computer from a Web page - that would be a huge security risk.

Instead, you have one of the following options:

1. Offer file download like you currently do, and let user take care of saving / copying / moving it to the desired directory.
2. Store data in one of virtual filesystems supported by Emscripten, e.g. IndexedDB - you can check all the options here: https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html
3. In latest Chrome & Edge, use the new File System Access API which allows to show e.g. a "save dialog" and let user pick directory where a file should be saved (although this won't give you much compared to the regular download dialog, and would limit the solution only to Chrome-based browsers). https://web.dev/file-system-access/